# Adapt resolution for different models, specifically iPhone X

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

How can I adapt the resolution of my game to fit the new dimensions of the iPhone X?

I was initializing my scenes using the following, which seemed to work for models outside of the iPhone X:

```
static let screenWidth  = 1334
static let screenHeight = 750

let scene = MenuScene(size: CGSize(width: GameViewController.screenWidth, height: GameViewController.screenHeight))
skView.presentScene(scene)
```

But now with the introduction of iPhone X, running on that device either cuts off a portion of the scene, or the image simply doesn't fit on the screen.

The weird part is, I can see my whole MenuScene, it just has black bars on the left and right of the screen. But my GameScene is initialized the same way yet I can't see the whole scene, parts are cut off on all edges.

```
 SceneCoordinator.shared.gameScene = GameScene(size: CGSize(width: GameViewController.screenWidth, height: GameViewController.screenHeight))

 let nextScene = SceneCoordinator.shared.gameScene
 nextScene!.scaleMode = .aspectFill

 self.scene?.view?.presentScene(nextScene!, transition: SKTransition.crossFade(withDuration: 1.0))
```

I would be fine if all my scenes looked like the MenuScene, where everything with the exception of black bars, but that doesn't seem to be the case although both MenuScene and GameScene are initialized the same way.

Comment: This is a **radical idea** but, Have you tried querying the screen's actual size at runtime with (e.g.) `UIScreen.main.bounds.size`?

Comment: Also, how does your hard-coded 1334 x 750 work on 5.5" devices (e.g. iPhone 8 **Plus**)?

Comment: Also, are you using a launch storyboard or launch images?  If you are using launch images, have you included iPhone X sized images?

Comment: [Update Apps for iPhone X - iOS - Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/ios/update-apps-for-iphone-x/) contains advice and links regarding how to design for iPhone X, including information about width and height. Also, [iPhone X - Overview - iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/iphone-x/) show a width of 375 points and a height of 812 points - which is what shows with `UIScreen.main.bounds.size`.

Comment: @NicolasMiari I haven't tried that, like getting the device size at run time and then setting it to whatever that is? I should gave that a shot!

Comment: The iPhone X is not a 9:16 device,  you need to treat cropping the same way you would treat it for iPads.  Create a "safe" zone for your content, and an "excess" zone for resolutions that do not conform to the designated aspect ratio

Comment: @NicolasMiari he is using .aspectFill, so he can hard code a scene size of 9x16 and it will work on all iOS 11 iPhones with the exception of X